# A new duplicate sign-out HTTP request is sent every time the user logs out: Angular, RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt, rxjs-observables, nebular

#### Issue description

First of all, let me start by saying that I am using **Angular 10 with the Nebular UI Library** for the front-end, **Node.js** for the back-end API, and **JWT with the email/password strategy** for authentication. I have noticed that *for every time the user sings-in and signs back out without refreshing the application, a new duplicate sign-out request is made to the server* (multiple http requests are being sent out).
**If you refresh the application after you sign back out though, the problem goes away**. I'm not sure if I'm skipping something or I'm simply ignorant on the right way to log out and sign back in using JWTs, but I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for days now with no success so I'm eager for some help.

**Current behavior:**

If the user were to sign in and logs back out again more than once, **the sign-out request made to the server is duplicated**. This issue persists REGARDLESS of if you use an http interceptor (NbAuthJWTInterceptor or otherwise).

**Expected behavior:**

If the user were to sign in and log back out again, **there should be NO redundant sign-out requests made to the server** regardless of how many times the user repeats these steps without refreshing the app.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. The first time the user signs in everything works fine and there are no duplicate requests made to the server when you log out.
2. After you **sign back in for the 2nd time** and **sign out for the 2nd time** without refreshing the application, the 2nd sign out request you make to the server will send out a duplicate sign-out request (2 identical sign-out requests are sent to the server).
3. If the user **signs in again for a 3rd time** and **signs back out for a 3rd time**, then 3 sign-out requests will be sent to the server (a total of 3 identical requests sent out).
4. If the user were to sign in and log back out again, **the sign-out request would sent be duplicated one more time** and a total of 4 identical sign-out requests would be sent out. This continues indefinitely.

Here is a screenshot from my dev-tools network tab for these 4 steps (after signing-in and signing back out 4 times):
[image: duplicates]

**Related code:**
On the client side I have the **header.component.ts** file from which the sign out process is initiated:

```
...
ngOnInit() {
    // Context Menu Event Handler.
    this.menuService.onItemClick().pipe(
      filter(({ tag }) => tag === 'my-context-menu'),
      map(({ item: { title } }) => title),
    ).subscribe((title) => {
      // Check if the Logout menu item was clicked.
      if (title == 'Log out') {

        // Logout the user.
        this.authService.logout('email').subscribe(() => {
          // Clear the token.
          this.tokenService.clear()
          // Navigate to the login page.
          return this.router.navigate([`/auth/login`]);
        });

      }
      if (title == 'Profile') {
        return this.router.navigate([`/pages/profile/${this.user["_id"]}`]);
      }
    });
}
...
```

On the server side, there is the sign-out API route that returns a successful 200 response:

```
// Asynchronous POST request to logout the user.
router.post('/sign-out', async (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re subscribing inside of another subscription. This causes another subscription to be made each time `this.menuService.onItemClick()` is called.

You need to use a flattening strategy by using the proper Rxjs operator (exhaustMap, concatMap, switchMap, mergeMap).

In your case I would refactor like this (don’t forget to **unsubscribe** to each subscription in **ngOnDestroy**)

```
const titleChange$ = this.menuService.onItemClick()
  .pipe(
    filter(({ tag }) => tag === 'my-context-menu'),
    map(({ item: { title } }) => title)
  );

this.logOutSubscription = titleChange$.pipe(
  filter((title) => title == 'Log out'),
  exhaustMap((title) => this.authService.logout('email')),
  tap(() => {
    this.tokenService.clear()
    this.router.navigate([`/auth/login`]);
})
.subscribe();

this.profileNavSubscription = titleChange$
  .pipe(
    filter((title) => title == 'Profile'),
    tap(title => {
      this.router.navigate([`/pages/profile/${this.user["_id"]}`])
    })
   .subscribe();
```

`

Comment: Thank you so for much! It worked with a few tweaks!